# Using currency in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, currency

I have a currency column in a MySQL table defined as DECIMAL(19,4). It is not a floating point number so there is no problem with loss of precision.

My question is how can I fetch it into PHP, manipulate it, and store it back into MySQL without precision loss. By default if I fetch it and manipulate it I believe it becomes a float.

My hypothesis is that I can use the following:

```
$price = $price * 100;
$price = (int) $price;
//do some manipulation here
$price = $price / 100;
//store back into MySQL database
```

Does this work?

I have also looked at storing as an integer and using BCMath, but am wondering if the above would work just as well.

Comment: You might consider doing all the manipulations within the database.

Comment: The one issue with that is I need to perform the calculations, then ask the user to verify if they want to proceed. If they proceed, then I will add it to the database.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of the actual arithmetic you are trying to do?  You should have little problem with division by 100 following multiplication by 100.

Comment: It would involve adding items in a shopping cart with a certain quantity at a certain price (price being taken from the product table) and possibly calculating some tax as well. If the user confirms payment then it will get added back to the database in an invoice table.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

For "normal" currencies and "normal" amounts of money, then double precision/decimal(19,4) is fine.  The precision for a double is 15 digits of precision.  That is a value like this 123,456,789,012,345.  Even at a fraction of a US cent, that represents up to 123 billion quite accurately.  Conversion between a decimal and double *using rounding* should be fine.

In other words, if you are working with amounts up to a million currency units and want precision down to one thousandth of the unit, then double precision should be fine.  If this is not the case, you might need a special math library to handle the arithmetic.  (Postgres has one built-in.)

There are situations where such a range isn't quite enough.  When Turkish Lira traded at over 1,000,000 to a dollar, then the range up to 1/1000 of a unit would only be less than one million dollars -- which might not be sufficient.  Or, if you are valuing financial portfolios, particularly using nominal values of trades, then the range might not be sufficient.

Comment: In regards to "using rounding" above, are you suggesting that instead of multiplying and converting to an int, that I just use round($product_price, 2) when it comes out of the database? And round($inv_total, 2) before it goes back into the database?

Comment: @kojow7 . . . Basically, yes.  That should work unless your calculations involve complex calculations or involve combining numbers with very different magnitudes.